# jquery countdown inside span tags instead of printed directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery countdown script that goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#getting-started').countdown('2015/01/15').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
         var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
            + '<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
            + '<span>%H</span> hours '
            + '<span>%M</span> minutes '
            + '<span>%S</span> seconds'));
      });
   });
</script>
```

And the HTML code like this:

```
<div class="timer">

   <div class="days-wrapper">
      <span class="days"></span> <br>days
   </div>

   <div class="hours-wrapper">
      <span class="hours"></span> <br>hours
   </div>

   <div class="minutes-wrapper">
      <span class="minutes"></span> <br>minutes
   </div>

   <div class="seconds-wrapper">
      <span class="seconds"></span> <br>seconds
   </div>

</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is basically put the countdown inside the HTML code. I tried to do it like this:

```
+ '<div class="hours-wrapper"><span class="hours">%H</span> <br></div>'
```

But that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmmevtht/

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle with your countdown script

Comment: What is `countdown`? Link to random libraries, we do not know them all.

Comment: My apologies, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/nmmevtht/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the script, based on what it is doing

```
$('#getting-started').countdown('2015/01/15').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    $(".days").text(event.strftime("%-d"));
    $(".hours").text(event.strftime("%H"));
    $(".minutes").text(event.strftime("%M"));
    $(".seconds").text(event.strftime("%S"));
});
```

---

And since you updated the question with your a fiddle, here it is running

```js
    $('#getting-started').countdown('2015/01/15').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        $(".days").text(event.strftime("%-d"));
        $(".hours").text(event.strftime("%H"));
        $(".minutes").text(event.strftime("%M"));
        $(".seconds").text(event.strftime("%S"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.0.4/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="getting-started"></div>

<p></p>

<div class="timer">

<div class="days-wrapper">
<span class="days"></span> <br>days
</div>

<div class="hours-wrapper">
<span class="hours"></span> <br>hours
</div>

<div class="minutes-wrapper">
<span class="minutes"></span> <br>minutes
</div>

<div class="seconds-wrapper">
<span class="seconds"></span> <br>seconds
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just target the `span` with the class name you want to add it to and pass each increment to it

```
$('#getting-started').countdown('2015/01/15').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
   $(".days").html(event.strftime('%-d'));
   $(".hours").html(event.strftime('%H'));
   $(".minutes").html(event.strftime('%M'));
   $(".seconds").html(event.strftime('%S'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmmevtht/1/)